# Why do almost all Chabad shuls always use the same tunes for certain parts of davening?

Tags: minhag, history, tefilla, music, chabad

I have noticed that at pretty much every Chabad shul I have ever attended, the same tunes were always used for certain parts of davening on Shabbos. For example, they all use the same tune for *ha-aderet v'ha-emunah* during *psukei d'zimra* as well as for the line in the *kedusha* for *musaf* that begins *hu Elokeinu, hu avinu*. They also all use the same tune for *ata bechartanu* during *yamim tovim*. Every Chabad shul also seems to sing *al tira...* at the end of davening, although I have noticed variations in the tune used.

Here are the tunes
- [Hu Elokeinu](http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/140731/jewish/Hu-Elokeinu.htm)
- [Ata Bechartanu](http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/140688/jewish/Atoh-Bechartonu.htm)

Is there a reason why almost every Chabad shul seems to use these tunes for these parts of davening? What is the origin of the tunes? Were they favorite *niggunim* of one of the rebbes? How long have Chabad shuls used these uniform tunes?

Comment: Fwiw my local _Chabad_ synagogue uses at least two different tunes for _Haederes V'hameuna_. It may the exception, though, for all I know. +1, anyway.

Comment: @msh210 That's interesting. I wonder if either of them is the one I'm thinking of. I'm pretty sure I've heard it in at least 5 or 6 different places.

Comment: There are three "official" Chabad niggunim for HoAderes VeHaemuna". One of them, however, doesn't generally "work well", so there are only two active niggunim.

Comment: Also, many Chabad rabbis pray in different Chabad houses and transfer melodies

Comment: I go to a Chabad shul out of convenience, and they typically use the same tunes. Sometimes they'll spice it up though.

Comment: With regards to Ha'aderet Ve'ha'emuna, are you referring to http://youtu.be/WgVzX4G0W6E?t=49s OR http://www.chabad.info/php/audio.php?action=playsong&id=683, or both?

Comment: there is a difference btween chabad houses and chabad shuls that are in lubavitch communities. Most chabad houses I've been to use more or less the same few tunes for everything while this isn't the case in chabad shuls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hu Elokeinu and Ato Vechartonu were introduced by the Rebbe and was always song in the Rebbe's presence. 
Hoaderes Vehoemuna -French National Anthem- was also introduced by the Rebbe but the other tune (the one that many Shuls use by Hakofos on Simchas Torah) was more common even during the Rebbe's presence.

Keily Attah (end of Hallel) was composed by the Alter Rebbe (first Chabad Rebbe).

Birkas Kohanim was composed by the Miteler Rebbe (second Chabad Rebbe)'s choir.

There are also Rosh Hashanah & Yom Kippur songs that they will sing in all Chabad Shuls like Hayom Teamtzeinu (which the Rebbe introduced as his father's Simchas Torah Niggun), Ovinu Malkeinu (composed by the Alter Rebbe), Mar'ei Kohen (Avodah YK) is not a "Rebbe song" but it was the song/tune used in the Rebbe's presence, Napolean March (sung at the very end of YK) was introduced by the Alter Rebbe.
What it boilsdown to is either a Niggun introduced/composed by a Rebbe or was always the exclusive tune used the Rebbe's presence.

Comment: It ignores songs like Lecha Dodi which aren't sung in 770 but are sungs in Chabad houses.

Comment: 1) I guess you haven't been in 770 in a while because they have been singing Lecha Dodi from way back from around the late 5740's. 2) There is no universal Chabad tune for Lecha Dodi, I haven't seen/heard two Chabad Shuls that use the same set tune every single week.

Comment: chabad *shuls* or chabad *houses*?

Comment: You wrote "it ignores songs like LD which aren't sung in 770", yet they do sing LD in 770!

Comment: different tunes

Comment: see http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/265770/jewish/Shabbat-Synagogue-Songs.htm

Comment: Marei Cohen sounds a lot like Kamofes Hayisi

Answer (score 3):

Generally, Chabad houses try to balance two different systems:

1. On one hand, you want people to be able to sing along. So they try to sing "famous" melodies, such as "Bei Ana Rachitz", "Lecha Dodi" or "Lechu Neranena".
2. Chabad houses try to follow 770's system (that's where most Shluchim spend time before/during Shlichus). They tend to sing official niggunim for certain parts of Davening. So that's the source of "ha-aderet v'ha-emunah", "hu Elokeinu, hu avinu", "Ata Vechartanu" etc.

Some tunes come from camps/schools, such as "Al Tirah"/"Ach Tzadikim".

Comment: What makes a nigun official? Being sung at 770? And where do the niggunim come from?

Comment: http://store.kehotonline.com/index.php?stocknumber=HO-HANI.S&deptid=&parentid=&page=2&itemsperpage=10 , songs sung in in front of the Rebbe or made by older chassidim

Comment: I doubt that many of these modern tunes were sung in earlier times. Chabad is a brand so it has to keep to it.

Comment: Some of the official tunes were written by the Rebbes for example the tune that most chabad houses sing to "Hu Elokeinu" was written by the current rebbe zya

Comment: @Yitzchak Hu Elokeinu was written by R' Isroel Halprin, the Chazzan in Lubavitch. It was popularized by the Rebbe. But yes, it is a "Rebbe's niggun"

Comment: @annex which? Bei Ana Rachitz?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I stand corrected. I assumed since I heard it called "The Rebbe's Niggun" so many times that it was written by him.

Comment: @Yitzchak http://www.chassidus.com/audio/nigun/12-11-Hu-Elokeinu-Heichal-Neginah.ram